# ¿Como aplicar dos funciones de transformación css al mismo elemento?

Tags: css, css-transform

estoy realizando un ejercicio en el sitio [Acamica](https://www.acamica.com/clases/1954/animaciones-en-css/multiples-transformaciones/desafio/1743) y me encuentro con que no puedo pasar el ejercicio, tal vez no entendí bien la lección.

En este ejercicio debo de:

- Mover el `elemento` 45px a la derecha
- y girarlo 30 grados

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```css
#elemento {
  transform: translateX(45px) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Transform</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    div {
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 40px auto;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Transformaciones</h1>

  <div id="elemento">elemento</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Sin embargo me marca

[image: que es incorrecto]

¿Por qué no la acepta?¿Cómo puedo corregir el ejercicio?

Comment: Pareciera ser un problema específico de ellos, yo los contactaría directamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer si hay otras formas de hacer lo mismo, las validaciones de la página solo aceptaban [una de tres posibles soluciones](https://globant.acamica.com/comunidad/9463/problema-con-ejercicio-36).

```css
#elemento {
  transform: translate(45px) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Transform</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    div {
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 40px auto;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Transformaciones</h1>

  <div id="elemento">elemento</div>

</body>

</html>
```